# Convert list of strings to array of strings - difference between (String[])list.toArray() and list.toArray(new String[0])

Tags: java, gwt

I have a `List<String>` in Java, and wanted to convert it to an array.

At first, I used the toArray syntax that takes an array as input, but then I switched to the no-parameter version, i.e. I went from:

```
String[] myArray = myList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

to

```
String[] myArray = (String[])myList.toArray();
```

Reading through the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html) (my underlying type is ArrayList), it seems that the functionality should be the same.  I thought the latter version was more efficient since it doesn't require allocating and collecting an empty array.  Am I missing any subtle differences?

(Note: the reason I'm asking is that GWT does treat the statements differently.  The latter gives a dynamic cast error while the former does not.  I just wanted to know if this is a nuance of how I'm using GWT or a nuance of how I'm using Java.)

Thanks!

Comment: About allocation of empty arrays: empty arrays are immutable, so each empty array you allocate refers to the same instance. You can allocate it once and reuse it anywhere. About performance: allocation of an empty array is really not what should bother you about performance.

Comment: +1 to what @svz said, though it's a different story in GWT: arrays map to JS arrays (which are mutable), each array allocation in Java (even for an empty array) results in an array invocation in the _compiled_ JavaScript.

Comment: @svz Thanks for explaining the immutability - that's good to know.  As for performance, yes, whether I allocate and deallocate an array is a very minor issue - but that's no excuse to not try to code as efficiently as possible.  Of course in this case, tracking down the issue cost more time than I'd like, so I'm hoping to understand why it is this way for next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`toArray()` returns an `Object[]`, not a `String[]` (remember: generics in Java work by type erasure, so an `ArrayList<String>` can in practice contain a `Number`), hence the *dynamic cast error* (aka `ClassCastException`).

The common way to use `toArray(…)` is to pass an array of the appropriate size, so no reallocation will be necessary:

```
String[] myArray = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me an idea of where my issue came from.  I'll have to study up more on Java generics - I came from a C++/C# world.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, option 2 is slightly more efficient for the reasons you specify.

```
String[] myArray = myList.toArray(new String[0]); /* option 1 */
String[] myArray = (String[])myList.toArray();    /* option 2 */
```

There is a third option that avoids any unnecessary allocation, and avoids the potential casting issue from option 2:

```
String[] myArray = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]); /* option 3 */
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, it can be achieved by

```
String[] myArray = myList.stream().toArray(String[]::new)
```